# TYPO3: How to use the element browser in an own backend module?

Tags: javascript, module, typo3, backend

I want to have a simple input field in an own TYPO3 8.7 backend module, what should be filled with a pageid after clicking a page in the element browser.

I tried a lot in the past but the main problem is an error-alert in the element browser when clicking a page with `Error - reference to main window is not set properly!`

My module.js file looks like at the moment:

```js
var setFormValueOpenBrowser;

define(['jquery', 'TYPO3/CMS/Lux/Vendor/Chart.min'], function($) {

 // define(['jquery', 'TYPO3/CMS/Lux/Vendor/Chart.min', 'TYPO3/CMS/Backend/FormEngine'], function($) {

 // main options
 // var FormEngine = {
 //  formName: TYPO3.settings.FormEngine.formName
 //  ,backPath: TYPO3.settings.FormEngine.backPath
 //  ,openedPopupWindow: null
 //  ,legacyFieldChangedCb: function() { !$.isFunction(TYPO3.settings.FormEngine.legacyFieldChangedCb) || TYPO3.settings.FormEngine.legacyFieldChangedCb(); }
 // };

 var url = '/typo3/index.php?route=%2Fwizard%2Frecord%2Fbrowse&token=53b5d23e8e661e465636a96ca618426cb293d0b5&mode=db&bparams=data[pages][2][content_from_pid]|||pages|';
 var popup = window.open(url, 'Typo3WinBrowser', 'height=600,width=800,status=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');
 popup.focus();

});
```

Of course, the token is hardcoded in this example - but that's not the problem.
BTW: If I try to also load FormEngine via require.js the console throws a `TypeError: TYPO3.settings.FormEngine is undefined`

Has anyone a working code for the usage of the element browser (files or pages) in an own backend module? Or is there an existing extension where I can dig into the code?

Comment: I've seen that there is another hidden field with the name <input name="data[pages][2][content_from_pid]" value="" type="hidden">. But adding this does not change anything.

Answer (score 5):

Although this question is a little outdated, here's how I did it:

This is in the controller of my extension

```
$options = [
        'renderType' => 'inputLink',
        'tableName' => 'myTable',
        'fieldName' => 'url',
        'databaseRow' => [
            'uid' => $myModel->getUid(),
            'pid' => 0
        ],
        'parameterArray' => [
            'fieldConf' => [
                'label' => 'URL',
                'config' => [
                    'eval' => 'trim',
                    'size' => 1024,
                ],
            ],
            'itemFormElValue' => $myModel->getUrl(),
            'itemFormElName' => 'data[myTable][editform][url]',
            'itemFormElID' => 'data[mytable][editform][url]',
            'field' => 'url',
            'fieldChangeFunc' => [
                'TBE_EDITOR_fieldChanged' => "TBE_EDITOR.fieldChanged('mytable','editform','url','data[mytable][editform][url]');"
                ],

        ]
    ];

        $nodeFactory = new NodeFactory();
        $linkField = new InputLinkElement($nodeFactory, $options);
        $urlField = $linkField->render();

        $this->view->assign('renderedUrlField', $urlField['html']);
```

Where «mytable» is the table the controller uses, «editform» is the form-name and «url» is the database-field that's been used to store the value.

For some reason, you need to name your form «editform», since a sysext-JS refers to that.

You need to add this to your controller to make this working:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\Element\InputLinkElement;
use TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\NodeFactory;
```

And in the fluid-template, you have to use:

```
<f:format.raw>{renderedUrlField}</f:format.raw>
```

because it returns html-code.

Regarding the javascript error: that's because the FormEngine wasn't initialized.

Add this to your Default.html in the section `<f:be.container...>`:

```
includeJsFiles="{
        1:'/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/jsfunc.tbe_editor.js',
3:'/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/jsfunc.inline.js',
        4:'/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/backend.js'
    }"

            includeRequireJsModules="{
        0:'{f:uri.resource(path:\'JavaScript/ckeditor/ckeditor.js\')}',
        4:'TYPO3/CMS/Backend/FormEngine',
        5:'TYPO3/CMS/Backend/FormEngineValidation',
        7:'TYPO3/CMS/Backend/ContextMenu',
        8:'TYPO3/CMS/Backend/FormEngineReview',
        9:'{f:uri.resource(path:\'JavaScript/main.js\')}'
      }"
```

I included ckeditor as well here.

And now, you need to initialize the FormEngine. I did this in main.js:

```
TYPO3.settings.FormEngine = {"formName":"editform"};

define(['jquery', 'TYPO3/CMS/Backend/FormEngine'], function($){
    'use strict';

    $(function(){
        TYPO3.FormEngine.initialize();
    });
});
```

The first line is important, otherwise, the JS will throw said error.

Hope this helps somebody.